# Error: required operator not found in Macro: SAS

Tags: macros, sas

I'm working on this macro (see below) and this statement is not resolving : %if (&var_len > &&max&i) %then %let max&i=&var_len; and the error that is returned is: ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: (&var_len > &&max&i)
ERROR: The macro PRCS_FREQ will stop executing

Does anyone have any idea on how I can improve this macro and to get this statement to resolve?

Macro:

```
%macro prcs_freq;
%do i=1 %to &n_of_var;
%global end&i f_line_count&i f_var&i;

%let max&i=1;
%let k=%eval(&i+1);
%if (&i < &n_of_var) %then %let end&i=%eval(&&cum&k-1);
%else %let end&i=&n_of_line;

%let f=%eval(&&cum&i+1);  /* line number for "Frequency" */
%let freq_pos&i=%index(%bquote(&&line&f),Frequency);  /* column position  of "Frequency" */
%let f_var&i=%upcase(%scan(%bquote(&&line&f),1,%str( )));
%let var_len=%length(&&f_var&i);
%let max&i=&var_len;

%global &&f_var&i;
%let &&f_var&i=&i; /* for Frequency */

%do j=&f+2 %to &&end&i;
  %let var_len=%length(%substr(%bquote(&&line&j),1,&&freq_pos&i-1));
  %if (&var_len > &&max&i) %then %let max&i=&var_len;
  %put *** f=&f  i=&i  j=&j  var_len=&var_len  freq_pos&i=&&freq_pos&i    
max&i=&&max&i  f_var&i=&&f_var&i;
%end; /* %do j= */
%let f_line_count&i=%eval(&&end&i-&&cum&i+1);
 %end; /* %do i= */

data _null_;
%do i=1 %to &n_of_var;
  file "&wk_dir/&&f_var&i...txt";
  %do j=&&cum&i %to &&end&i;
    put "%substr(%bquote(&&line&j),1,&&max&i+5)%substr(%bquote  (&&line&j),&&freq_pos&i)";
  %end;
%end;
run;



 /* test */
 %put =====;
 %put ===== Frequency;
 %put =====;
 %do i=1 %to &n_of_var;
 %put f_var&i=&&f_var&i   cum&i=&&cum&i   end&i=&&end&i          f_line_count&i=&&f_line_count&i   &&f_var&i=&&&&&&f_var&i;
%end;
%mend prcs_freq;
```

Comment: What do you get in the log at that point if you add something like `%put var_len = "&var_len" max_i = "&&max&i";` ? This would probably make it easier to debug.

Comment: I tried something similar before and got the same error. Here's what I get when running your code: SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 6
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable FREQ_POS6 resolves to 35
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable VAR_LEN resolves to 10                       )
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: &var_len > &&max&i
SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 6
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable MAX6 resolves to 11
ERROR: The macro PRCS_FREQ will stop executing.
MLOGIC(PRCS_FREQ):  Ending execution.

Comment: You're missing a `%eval` in this: `%do j=&f+2 %to &&end&i;` A `%eval` is required around `&f+2`.

Comment: Your symbolgen log shows VAR_LEN resolves to: 10). I suspect the unmatched close parenthesis is the problem. It's possible coming from &&line&j.

Comment: I added an answer below, but would be curious what this macro is doing?  What are the &lines being processed?  Is it processing data created from .lst output from PROC FREQ ?  It could be there is an easier way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: mjsqu- I tried your suggestion, but still get the same error. I tried combining both yours and Quentin, but have the final error as stated below his answer.

Answer (score 1):

The symbolgen log shows that your macro variable &VAR_LEN resolves to: 10) .  That unmatched parenthesis causes the problem, e.g.:

```
188  %macro ck;
189    %if 10) > 0 %then %put true;
190  %mend;
191  %ck;
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: 10) > 0
ERROR: The macro CK will stop executing
```

The open parenthesis is the missing operator referred to in the error.  I think the source of the extra unmatched parenthesis is this line:

```
%let var_len=%length(%substr(%bquote(&&line&j),1,&&freq_pos&i-1));
```

I think &&line&j is resolving to a value that has an unmatched close parenthesis.  %BQUOTE would quote (mask) the parenthesis.  But %substr() would unquote it.  And then the %length function would see the close parenthesis as the end of the call to %length. Then the close parenthesis you mean to be the end of the call to %length becomes the extra parenthesis.  If you change to %qsubstr() it should quote the parenthesis, and work appropriately.

Below is a test macro, illustrating what I think is the problem:

```
%macro test(line= ) ;
  %put &=line ;

  %let bad_var_len =%length( %substr(%bquote(&line),1,12)) ;
  %let good_var_len=%length(%qsubstr(%bquote(&line),1,12)) ;

  %put &=bad_var_len ;
  %put &=good_var_len ;

  %if &bad_var_len>0 %then %put true ;
%mend test;
```

Here is the log from running it:

```
219  %test(line=%str(Hi mom%) how are you?))
LINE=Hi mom) how are you?
BAD_VAR_LEN=6 how )
GOOD_VAR_LEN=12
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: &bad_var_len>0
ERROR: The macro TEST will stop executing.
```

Comment: I made the recommended change and now I am getting this error: MLOGIC(PRCS_FREQ):  %LET (variable name is END10)
SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable K resolves to 11
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable CUM11 resolves to 38E3
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric
       operand is required. The condition was: 38E3-1
ERROR: The macro PRCS_FREQ will stop executing.
MLOGIC(PRCS_FREQ):  Ending execution.

Comment: The macro is using a .lst in order to generate .txt for each individual var that can then be used in a html as an interactive link. I think there might be a better way, but this is the best I have right now. The univariate procedure is working fine, but I can't seem to get this one to work. I tried something else that was slightly different from your suggestion and ended up with the same exact error. Greatly appreciate your help. Your fix was shorter than mine, but I can't seem to get past the errors.

Comment: Is that new error coming from %let end&i=%eval(&&cum&k-1);  ? Try changing from %eval to %sysevalf. I believe it can handle math with exponential notation. Expression 38e3-1 will crash %eval, as shown in the err message.

Comment: I'm not getting an error now, but it seems to be getting stuck on an infinite iteration loop. I'm getting a lot of warnings especially around the %qsubstr (argument 3 to macro function %qsubstr is out of range) and apparrent symbolic reference at line25272

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to debug each error as it comes up.  (such is the life of a programmer!).  Suggest %put the macro variables associated with an error to see what they resolve to, then making a small test case/macro that you can debug more easily.  For example, this test case shows the type of code that can generate the argument 3 out of range error.  %put %qsubstr(Hello,1,2);  %put %qsubstr(Hello,1,5);  %put %qsubstr(Hello,1,6);  Good luck.  Suggest post new, smaller questions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Doing complex calculations in macro code is frustrating and hard to debug. Since your macro is already generating a data step I suggest that you just replace a lot of the macro calculations with data step code.  You can use CALL SYMPUTX() to generate any new macro variables that you need for later steps of the macro.